# Why CSS hover effect with class selector does not work with nested layout?

Tags: css

Simple code.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b2d0fyv/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="header">
            <div class="nav">
                <div class="navTitle">1</div>
                <div class="subNav subNav1">test1</div>
                <div class="subNav subNav2">test2</div>
                <div class="subNav subNav3">test3</div>
                <div class="subNav subNav4">test4</div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="container">

        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <div class="leftEles leftEle1"></div>
            <div class="leftEles leftEle2"></div>
            <div class="leftEles leftEle3"></div>
            <div class="leftEles leftEle4"></div>
            <div class="leftEles leftEle5"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">

        </div>




        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And CSS.

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #0092C7;
    position: relative;
}

.left{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.leftEles{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F4F3DE;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.leftEles:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.nav{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    line-height: 50px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}

.navTitle{
    border-left: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}

.subNav{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background-color: rgba(0,146,199,0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.subNav:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I'm curious why the hover and cursor effect on .subNav won't work!

Simple and silly question. Help me, many thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your effect was not working because of `.container` is overlapping `.header`

Use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) css on `.header`:

```
z-index: 2;
```

Complete css of `.header`

```
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:2;
    background-color: #0092C7;
    position: relative;
}
```

## [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4b2d0fyv/4/)

Comment: Please, never use so stupid z-indexes. What you don´t use normally 2?

Answer (score 2):

`.container` is positioned over navigation, has higher natural z-index (in code is after navigation).

To place navigation over container, set to navigation `position: relative` (only positioned elements (excluding `position: static;`) works with z-index) and higher `z-index` than 1.

```
.nav{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    line-height: 50px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4b2d0fyv/3/